# unable to assume role with gitlab oidc and AWS

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, aws-iam-policy

I have configured the `IAM Role` with the below definition. I am getting the AccessDenied error when I configure the condition below. Where am I going wrong?

Access Denied

```
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "gitlab.com:sub": "https://gitlab.com/pradeepkumarl/configure-openid-connect-in-aws::ref_type:branch:ref:main"
            }
        }
```

Total policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:oidc-provider/gitlab.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "gitlab.com:sub": "https://gitlab.com/pradeepkumarl/configure-openid-connect-in-aws::ref_type:branch:ref:main"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your sub field under condition. It should be of the form project_path::ref_type:branch:ref:. You don't need to include the Gitlab url.

Also keep in mind that you may need to change the condition from "StringEquals" to "StringLike" to accommodate wildcards, as mentioned in the troubleshooting section of the documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/aws/index.html